# Call struts2 action method on page load

Tags: javascript, java, struts2, action, pageload

How to call action method on page load?
Below is my action method

```
    public String **getlist**() {
              myList=dao.getList();
                return "success" ;
      }
```

I want to load the data on index.jsp page by executing the `getList` on page load.

How can i do that? What will be the `result type` in `web.xml`. Better u suggest the content type of `web.xml`

Comment: I don't understand the question. The action is hit during page load. Action properties are available in the associated JSP. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Hi Dave, I want to execute action on page load and not on click of any button or link.

Comment: What's the actual *problem*? Presumably you're *already* calling an action on page load: all pages go through an action to begin with. That's how it works.

Comment: Generally action method is called upon click of any button. I have index.jsp page on which list of users should get loaded when the url is accessed.
Hope u understand the issue now.

Comment: If your app is hitting JSP pages without going through actions I'd argue you're using the framework wrong. Have the landing page go through an action and problem solved--I don't understand the issue.

Comment: In any case, there's the `<s:action>` tag (which I recommend essentially never), a normal Ajax request that returns JSON and you then JavaScript the data into the page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In index.jsp specify a javascript section. Then in this section submit the form like **form1.submit()**; Here form1 is id of the form. write this code inside document.ready method of JQuery in javascript section. This will submit the form on page load and action specify in this form will we called and hit the getList() of action on page load.

Comment: and what should be result page and type I should mention?

Comment: if you have'nt used tiles then result page will be index.jsp and in type you have to mention jsp.

Comment: It will go in infinite loop. Because next time at page loading it will again do form.submit();

Comment: if index.jsp is first page of your application. Then you can make an ajax call on page load to call that method. In this case page will not refreshed and infinite loop will not occur.

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying. Can u please provide me piece of code for ajax as I am in learning phase of ajax?
Also suggest the result section in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(this).processRequest({
        url: url
    });
});
<action name="actionName"   class="fullpathofClass" method="**getlist**">
        <result name="success">jsp loaded</result>
</action>
```

In java script section add the document .ready function and apply the xml configration as the specified below to the to get the result